# Splitting recording in Audio Hijack Pro on spotify track change (Applescript)

Tags: audio, split, applescript, spotify

This is similar to: [Monitoring Spotify track change in Applescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642467/monitoring-spotify-track-change-in-applescript/8174754#8174754)
but instead of displaying track changes in growl notifications, I'd like to make Audio Hijack Pro split its current recording. Audio Hijack Pro also supports Applescript, and the command would be "split recording". So I don't need any information about which song is playing, but the track change as an event that triggers "split recording" accurately on time. I'd like to start with something but i know very little about scripting in general and even less about Applescript. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This is an even better script.
It will take the album name and track name and put in into the filename and split the tracks automatically on detection on a new track being played.

found on: http://joonix.se/post/25716608379/spotify-offline-playlist This is an Applescript and should be saved with the extension .scpt

```
property update_delay : 0.1

tell application "Audio Hijack Pro"
    activate
    -- Create a new session "Spotify" if it doesn't already exist
    try
        set spotify_session to first session whose name is "Spotify"
        if output name format of spotify_session is not "%tag_artist - %tag_title" then
            display dialog "The existing profile for \"Spotify\" does not utilize %tag_artist and %tag_title in the output name format option. Please add this if you want your files to be named automatically or delete/rename your existing \"Spotify\" session."
        end if
    on error number -1719
        tell application "Finder"
            set spotify_path to POSIX path of (application file id "spty" as alias)
        end tell
        set spotify_session to make new application session at end of sessions
        set targeted application of spotify_session to spotify_path
        set output folder of spotify_session to "~/Desktop"
        set output name format of spotify_session to "%tag_artist - %tag_title"
        set recording format of spotify_session to {encoding:MP3, bit rate:320, channels:Stereo, style:VBR}
    end try
    set name of spotify_session to "Spotify"

    -- (Re-)start hijacking and recording on the spotify session
    if hijacked of spotify_session is true then
        stop hijacking spotify_session
    end if
    start hijacking spotify_session relaunch yes
end tell

tell application "Spotify"
    if not running then activate
    if player state is playing then pause

    display dialog "Start playing the tracks that you want to rip with Audio Hijack, quit spotify when done."
    if repeating then display dialog "Please notice that you have repeating enabled in Spotify!"

    set has_started to false -- Whether spotify have been playing yet

    -- Check for changes to current track until spotify exits
    repeat until application "Spotify" is not running
        -- Changed track
        if has_started and id of current track is not recording_id then
            tell application "Audio Hijack Pro" to stop recording spotify_session
            set has_started to false
        end if

        -- Started playing
        if has_started is not true and player state is playing then
            set has_started to true
            set recording_id to id of current track

            -- Get the metadata
            set track_name to name of current track
            set track_artist to artist of current track
            set track_album to album of current track

            tell application "Audio Hijack Pro"
                set title tag of spotify_session to track_name
                set artist tag of spotify_session to track_artist
                set album tag of spotify_session to track_album

                start recording spotify_session
            end tell
        end if

        -- Stopped playing
        if has_started and player state is not playing then
            tell application "Audio Hijack Pro" to stop recording spotify_session
            set has_started to false
        end if

        delay update_delay
    end repeat

    tell application "Audio Hijack Pro" to stop recording spotify_session
end tell
```

Comment: tx. Works like a charm!

Comment: Great script! Any chance this can be modified to be used with iTunes Radio?

Comment: ps: the script's been updated to so rip the track number and other metadata too: http://joonix.se/post/42126024780/spotify-apple-script-update-and-flattr

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeatedly poll the current playing track and when the name of the track changes, send the command to Audio Hijack Pro.

This can probably be done with an event in Spotify. I'll check the documentation. In the meantime ...

```
tell application "Spotify"
  set currentTrack to (name of current track)
  repeat
    if currentTrack is not equal to (name of current track)
      set currentTrack to (name of current track)
      tell application "Audio Hijack Pro"
        split recording theSession
      end tell
    end if
  end repeat
end tell
```

In fact, I've just submitted a gist that may help https://gist.github.com/3604106

Hope it helps.